# What are MongoDB binaries and where are they located?

Tags: windows, mongodb

I am trying to upgrade a local version of MongoDB that is installed on my windows 10 computer. I am trying to upgrade my local MongoDB version to v^4.0.0 from v3.6.3. From the MongoDB [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/upgrade-revision/#upgrade-replace-binaries) the instructions are to `Replace the Existing Binaries`.

So, what are binaries in mongodb and where can I find them?

My current MongoDB instance(v3.6.3) is located in C:\mongodb\bin. Where can I find the binaries?

[Here is where I am currently downloading the MongoDB files](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/community) but I am not sure if they are binaries. Do the zip or msi files contain binaries?/ Are they binaries?

Comment: `C:\mongodb\bin` - those are your binaries. Thats where you find your `mongod`, `mongo`, etc. programs. Also, see [Install MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/installation/).

Comment: Just make sure to have a backup copy of your data - and then upgrade.

Comment: Oh!!! `bin` stands for binaries. Face palm. Now I get it. 

So all I have to do after creating a backup is replace the bin folder with a bin folder of the version I want to upgrade to? Where do I get the new version bin folder? Do I have to install that MongoDB version first?

Comment: Here are instructions to a [Upgrade to Standalone 4.0](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.0-upgrade-standalone/index.html).